# Conversor de Divisas JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Este es mi código JS para el conversor; necesito una mano para poder agregar un código que recupere la información de las conversiones realizadas en cada inicio de la página para mostrarle al usuario el historial de las mismas

````
let almacenarEnLocal = [] // <= ARREGLO QUE IRA AL LOCALSTORAGE
let divisa = document.querySelector('.divisa')

function calcular() {
  const primerMonedaIngresada = primerDivisa.value 
  const segundaMonedaIngresada = segundaDivisa.value

  fetch(`https://v6.exchangerate-api.com/v6/fdca511a8ae4e70ce6d7b7f6/latest/${primerMonedaIngresada}`)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    const taza = data.conversion_rates[segundaMonedaIngresada]
    infoDeCambio.innerHTML = `<b>1 ${primerMonedaIngresada}</b> es igual a: <b>${taza.toFixed(2)} ${segundaMonedaIngresada}</b>`
    segundoValor.value = (primerValor.value * taza).toFixed(2)

    botonConvertir.addEventListener('click', botonClick)
  })
}

function botonClick() { //MOSTRAR CONTENIDO EN EL DOM
  const li = document.createElement('li')
  li.classList = 'lista'
  const agregarEnLista = ul

  li.innerHTML = `La conversión de <b>$${primerValor.value} ${primerDivisa.value}</b> es igual a: <b>$${segundoValor.value} ${segundaDivisa.value}</b>`

  agregarEnLista.appendChild(li)
  li.appendChild(borrarResultados())
  almacenarEnLocal.push(li.innerHTML)

  localStorage.setItem("Conversiones", JSON.stringify(almacenarEnLocal)) // <= ARREGLO ALMACENADO EN EL LOCALSTORAGE
}```
````

Comment: Y la pregunta es??????

Comment: Como recupero la información de las conversiones realizadas y las pinto para que cuando se reinicie la pagina  el usuario pueda ver el historial de las conversiones

Comment: Hola, Iñaki. ¿Qué has intentado?